# DateTimeOffset?.ToString(string format)

Tags: c#

I have a `DateTimeOffset?` object which I want to format according to some datetime format.

I found that type `DateTimeOffset` has `ToString(String,IFormatProvider)` method:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb351892(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb351892%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But neither does this exist for an object of type `DateTimeOffset?`, nor can I find specifics on this type, or how to convert it.

What is `DateTimeoffset?`, and how do I convert it to a string using custom format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTimeOffset?` is the same as `Nullable<DateTimeOffset>` which has a `.Value` property to get the underlying `DateTimeOffset` value:

```
DateTimeOffset? dto;
...
string s = dto.Value.ToString(String,IFormatProvider);
```

Note that you should check to make sure the nullable `DateTimeOffset` *has* a value before calling `.Value`, otherwise you'll get a `NullReferenceException`:

```
DateTimeOffset? dto;
...
if(dto.HasValue)
    string s = dto.Value.ToString(String,IFormatProvider);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTimeoffset?` is a nullable version of `DateTimeoffset`, nothing more. You can access its value using `.Value`.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx has more detailed information.